# proving a subset of Hilbert space is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H=L_2(0,1)$. and $M\subset H$ is the subset of functions such that $\int_o^1u(x)dx=0$. I think $H$ is obviously is a Hilbert space, but how can I prove that M is a closed subspace? Does the integral mean that $<u,1>=0$ and what this mean?

Comment: It means $M=1^\perp$, and as such it is closed.

Comment: Does this mean that the orthogonal complement of M would be $M^{\perp}=1^{\perp \perp}=1$?

Comment: Well, it's the span of the constant 1, i.e. the set of all constant functions.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what $1^{\perp}$ would be? What does the orthogonal complement of all constant functions mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you denote by $<f,g>:= \int_0^1 f/t)g(t) dt $ and the constant function which maps any argument to the constant as $1$, then yes, $M=\{u\in L_2(0,1): <u,1>=0 \}$ is closed, because $h(u) :=<u,1> $ is a continuous function, and therefore $M=h^{-1}(\{0\})$ as reverse image for the closed image $\{0\}$ is closed as well.
Furthermore it is even closed in the weak topology of that Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

Well, suppose that $u \in H$ is the limit of $\{u_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq M$. Then:
$$\left| \int u \right| \leq \int |u-u_n| +\left| \int u_n \right| = ||u-u_n||_1 + 0.$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality the $L_1$ norm is bounded above by the $L_2$ norm. Therefore:
$$\left| \int u \right| \leq ||u-u_n||_2 \to 0.$$
Therefore $u \in M$, which is indeed a closed subspace.